# How to remove the StringBuilder object from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, stringbuilder

I am trying to remove the `StringBuilder` object from an `ArrayList`, but I'm unable to do that. If I pass this line `al.remove("haiti");` that's a string object and is not equals to the `StringBuilder` and it returns to `false`. I tried with `al.remove(new StringBuilder("haiti"))`, but that doesn't work as well. Can anyone help?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<StringBuilder> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(new StringBuilder("3")); // [3]
        al.add(new StringBuilder("haiti")); // [3, haiti]
        System.out.println(al); // [3, haiti]
        System.out.println(al.remove(new StringBuilder("haiti")));
        // false, but I want true XD

        System.out.println(al); // Actual [3, haiti], Expected: [3]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *Java 8* you can use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```java
List<StringBuilder> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(new StringBuilder("3"));
al.add(new StringBuilder("haiti"));

System.out.println(al); // [3, haiti]
// if the string contained in StringBuilder is equal to the
// desired string, then remove this element from the list
System.out.println(al.removeIf(sb -> sb.toString().equals("haiti"))); // true
System.out.println(al); // [3]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to use StringBuilder inside the reduce method in java 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553362/15309136)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `StringBuilder` is to be a temporary object for constructing a `String` in several steps. It does not override `equals` and `hashCode`, so no two `StringBuilder` instances will be equal, even if they have the same contents (which can be changed in each). The only ways to remove one from a `List` are by index or by passing the reference to the same object itself.

That said, putting `StringBuilder` into a list like this doesn't make much sense; `StringBuilder` usually only lives inside a single method, then its `toString()` result is returned. You probably should be handling your data in an entirely different manner.

Answer (score 1):

As chrylis said, the usage of `StringBuilder` is not understood in this case.

I guess you would use `String` instead of `StringBuilder`.
Something like:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("3"); // [3]
        al.add("haiti"); // [3, haiti]
        System.out.println(al); // [3, haiti]
        System.out.println(al.remove("haiti"));

        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

What do you think?