# How to improve pervormance of String processing using Stream#reduce?

Tags: java, string, performance, java-stream

In my legacy project this code executes more than one minute for 10000 elements

```
private ByteArrayInputStream getInputStreamFromContactFile(MyDTO contacts) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            byte[] bytes = contacts.getLines()
                    .stream()
                    .map(lineItem -> lineItem.value)
                    .reduce(contacts.getHeader().concat("\n"), (partialString, el) -> partialString + el+ '\n')
                    .getBytes();
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        } finally {
            log.info("Duration is {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }
```

Is there any obvious way to make it faster ?

Comment: You basically just want to join the lines with `\n`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: convert List<String> to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string)

Comment: @WJS As I've already mentioned this code is legacy

Comment: Didn't mean `you` personally. But I presume you know what each map/method returns and the expected final result.

Comment: @WJS I shared all the context I have. I know that this code is semantically correct but slow.

Comment: Is the return type required to be `ByteArrayInputStream` or is an `InputStream` sufficient? Other point: the code is *not*  semantically correct. The reduction function is not associative and the identity element is not really an identity element. Java `Stream`’s `reduce` is not a left-fold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is really important using a `StringBuilder` will help, but look a bit less functional.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(contacts.getHeader());
builder.append("\n");
contacts.getLines()
    .stream()
    .map(lineItem -> lineItem.value)
    .forEach(line -> {
      builder.append(line);
      builder.append("\n");
    });
builder.toString().getBytes();
```

Comment: this looks a bit weird....

`builder.append(contacts.getLines()` and inside you you do `builder.append...`

Comment: yeas that was wrong, it I messed it up when editing the answer.

Comment: `list.stream().map().forEach()` is a bit redundant, may be changed to `list.forEach(line -> builder.append(line.value).append("\n"))`

Comment: Thanks!
now it takes 20-40 ms in average. Before ot was 50 seconds.

I am really surprised.

Comment: Hmm, @WJS answer seems to be the fastest because it uses plain loop without overhead on Stream API.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for over `10_000_000` lines of `36` characters each, this ran in under `4` seconds.  Not certain if it does what you want though.

```
private ByteArrayInputStream getInputStreamFromContactFile(MyDTO contacts) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(contacts.getHeader()).append("\n");
       for (String lineItem : contacts.getLines()) {
          sb.append(lineItem).append("\n");
        }
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());

     } finally {
        log.info("Duration is {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
     }
}
```

Comment: will share my results as soon as my environment is ready

Comment: Yes, it worked.
I've shared my results here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849950/how-to-improve-pervormance-of-string-processing-using-streamreduce/68850086#comment121681789_68850086

Comment: Note that `getBytes()` uses the system’s default charset. It’s better to specify a charset explicitly. You can use `ByteBuffer bb = Charset.defaultCharset().encode(CharBuffer.wrap(sb)); return new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array(), bb.arrayOffset(), bb.limit());` which does the same but encodes the `StringBuilder`’s content directly, without copying it into a new `String` first.

Comment: @Holger Well of course,  It's so obvious.  :)   I'm going to have to look at the source(s) and see exactly what is going on.  That is something I would never have thought to do.

Answer (score 1):

In order to improve performance it may be better to use intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream` + `OutputStreamWriter` to concatenate the values.

The byte array of the concatenated result is returned by [`ByteArrayOutputStream::toByteArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--)

```java
private ByteArrayInputStream getInputStreamFromContactFile(MyDTO contacts) throws IOException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(bos);
        writer.write(contacts.getHeader());
        writer.write("\n");

        contacts.getLines().forEach(line -> { 
            try {
                writer.write(line.value);
                writer.write("\n");
            } catch (IOException ioex) { throw new RuntimeException(ioex);}
        });
        writer.flush();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    } finally {
        log.info("Duration is {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
}
```

Another approach could be to use [`Collectors.joining` with prefix and suffix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```java
private ByteArrayInputStream getInputStreamFromContactFile(MyDTO contacts) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(
            contacts.getLines()
                .stream()
                .map(item -> item.value)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", contacts.getHeader().concat("\n"), "\n"))
                .getBytes()
        );
    } finally {
        log.info("Duration is {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
}
```

---

If it is really necessary to use `Stream::reduce` operation (due to some reason) with `StringBuilder`, the [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65960057/how-to-use-stringbuilder-inside-the-reduce-method-in-java-1-8) may be applied:

```java
private static ByteArrayInputStream getInputStreamFromContactFileReducing(MyDTO contacts) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        byte[] bytes = contacts.getLines()
                               .stream()
                               .map(lineItem -> lineItem.value)
                               .reduce(new StringBuilder().append(contacts.getHeader()).append("\n"),
                                       (sb, line) -> sb.append(line).append('\n'),
                                       (sb1, sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2))
                               .toString()
                               .getBytes();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    } finally {
        log.info("Reducing: Duration is {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
}
```

Comment: why your second approach should be better than original in my topic? could you please explain?

Comment: This form of `Collectors.joining` uses `StringJoiner` which is based on a `StringBuilder` and here one instance of the `StringBuilder` should be created -- it is basically similar to @LeonardBrünings answer.  In the original code, concatenation in `reduce` part: `partialString + el+ '\n'` is likely to create multiple Strings / StringBuilders.